# Classic ASP check with result set changes

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I hope I can explain this as I mean it!

I have an SQL query which has been formed as a View to make it easier to pull the data.

However, I have a week number column which gets the date and then calculates the week number.  I have everything outputted into an FPDF document, but I need to split the cells after the week number changes, then display a total for that week number.

How would I go about checking when the week number column changes?  I just can't think of a solution to this.

This is the code I have currently which doesn't work, there is a very high probability that this isn't right whatsoever.

```
if iCounter > 1 Then      
    NewSum = rs("W")     
    rs.moveprevious
    if StrComp(NewSum,rs("W")) = 1 Then
        pdf.Cell 15,5,"EOM",1,1,"C",1 
    else    
        rs.movenext     
        pdf.Cell 15,5,"",1,1,"C",1     
    End if
end if
```

Comment: Hi @Hyperjase, would it be possible for you to include some code in your question so we can see your problem in context?

Comment: Off the top of my head if your data is in weekno order you could use a variable to track the weekno, the total for that weekno in the loop and check if the weekno changes when it does break to a new row output the total, then reset the total and set the weekno variable to the new weekno. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a potential opportunity for `GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, MyDateColumn)`.

Comment: @Bond put it as an answer +1

Comment: @Bond Good approach. Have across situations myself where weekno in terms of calendar week might not fit for example some companies have a specific weekno schedule based on a tax year for example. So it really depends on how Hyperjase *calculates the week number* but still a sound approach. +1

Comment: Thanks for the info Bond and Lankymart.  For simplistic terms, then Week Number is actually generated from a second table which has every single day in and the week number it would be associated with.  I don't think I can use a GROUP BY as I need the result set as it is, I need to calculate this within Classic ASP/VBScript, then when the week number changes, add all the totals up from the previous week number.  What @Lankymart originally suggested is likely closer to what I need, I'm just not that converse with ASP/VBScript to know exactly what I need to do.

Comment: @Hyperjase Have you got some code you can share so far? and we will see what we can do to help.

Comment: Updated my first question with the code I currently have.

Comment: Thanks @Hyperjase Where is your `ADODB.Recordset` loop for the different rows?

Comment: @Lankymart in order of how the code appears, this is the code I have : _rs.Open sql,conn_ then the record set is pulled within a **While Wend** loop with a _rs.movenext_ within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario there are different ways to approach this, personally I've always found using  Arrays a lot easier more flexible and more efficient than using the `ADODB.Recordset`.

Once you have a `ADODB.Recordset` object regardless of the approach (be it `ADODB.Command`, `Recordset.Open()` or `Connection.Execute()`) you can convert it to a two dimensional array using `Recordset.GetRows()`.

Using your example I would structure your code like this;

> *Please take into consideration this is untested and coded from memory, I just wanted to give you the general gist of how to do this kind of computation in a Classic ASP environment.*

```vb
Dim rs, data, row, rows
Dim weekno
Dim total_weekno, current_weekno

'Assuming you have instantiated your rs object
'...

'Convert to an Array variable (data)
If Not rs.EOF Then data = rs.GetRows()
'Close and release Recordset from memory
Call rs.Close()
Set rs = Nothing

If IsArray(data) Then
  rows = UBound(data, 2)

  'Iterate through the array
  For row = 0 To rows
    'Assuming weekno column is the first in your resultant columns.
    weekno = data(0, row)
    If weekno = current_weekno Then
      'Increment our total for the current weekno by 1.
      total_weekno = total_weekno + 1
    Else
      'Place logic for adding new row to PDF here.
      'Use total_weekno to display the incremented total.

      'Afterward reset total_weekno for the new current weekno.
      total_weekno = 0
      'Our weekno has changed so set current weekno.
      current_weekno = weekno
    End If
  Next
End If
```